# MVVM - Where to format data after retrieving from from repository class?

Tags: android, android-mvvm

In my `fragment` class, I'm calling the `ViewModel` to retrieve data from the `repository`. I have gotten a simple example to work, now I'm trying to format the data (for example changing the Name String for each user based on some certain value). But I'm extremely confused on where to format the data, and exactly how to format the LiveData?

```
//Fragment class

private void setListener() {
        //Listening for new data
        mViewModel.getMembersLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ResponseBody responseBody) {
                if (responseBody != null) {
                    loadDataIntoRecycler(responseBody);
                } 
            }
        });

        //Call viewmodel to perform query
        int id = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(mContext).getId();
        mViewModel.getMembers(id);
}
```

Inside my ViewModel:

```
public class MembersViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private LiveData<ResponseBody> mMembersLiveData;
    private UserRepo               mRepo;

    public MembersViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public void init() {
        mRepo = new UserRepo();
        mMembersLiveData = mRepo.getMembersLiveData();
    }

    //Call Repo class to query for data

    public void getMembers(int id) {
        mRepo.getMembers(id);
    }

    public LiveData<ResponseBody> getMembersLiveData() {
        return mMembersLiveData;
    }
}
```

Repository class:

```
public class UserRepo {

    private static final String TAG = "UserRepo";

    private MutableLiveData<ResponseBody> mMembersLiveData;
    private UserService                   mUserService;

    public UserRepo() {
        mMembersLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

        Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
        mUserService = retrofit.create(UserService.class);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<ResponseBody> getMembersLiveData() {
        return mMembersLiveData;
    }


    public void getMembers(int id) {
        Call<ResponseBody> call = mUserService.GetUserFamilyMembers(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    mMembersLiveData.postValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                mMembersLiveData.postValue(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Better do it in `VM` by using a mediator live data . You can do it in repo but in this way that API could not be used anywhere Else because u modified the data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In above case, please format / transform data inside `ViewModel`.
This will lead to clean code and also you get space for future modifications.

There are many different ways to transform live data.
Please refer to this [LINK](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) and navigate to section **Transform LiveData**.
It consist of helpful and easy examples and will give you a direction to start..